# Is there a way to turn an escape sequence into a string?

Tags: c, string, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add escape sequences from a string into a linked list.

If I have a string "Hello\nMoo\tCow " is there a way to save \n and \t as a string? What about a space?

I'd want to linked list to end up holding these as strings so it would potentially look like this

"Hello" -> "\n" -> "Moo" -> "Cow" -> " " -> /

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through your string, you'd stop at whitespace characters as the word delimiters. At that point you can check what kind of whitespace character is separating your words and depending on that, add the appropriate escape sequence to your linked list. Does that sound about right?